# How to refer to a relative range in an ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I let each cell in the B column be the sum of the previous 3 cells in the A column? I could write the formula `=SUM(A1:A3)` in cell B3 and "pull it down", but I want to solve this with a single formula in B3 (or B1).

```
   A   B
1  1  
2  1  
3  2   4
4  3   6
5  5  10
6  8  16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMIF like this:

B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A20),"<="&ROW(A3:A20),A1:A20))
```